# Im trying to retrieve data from mysql with MAMP

Tags: php, android, mysql, mamp

hi guys I'm trying to retrieve data from mysql server with php, but the variable with `YYYY-MM-DD` it not working without date variable it works, anyone know what happened ?

If I try do in MAMP command line work but sending data from url no, please help thanks

pd: sorry for my english and on my local server date value its a date type thanks

`http://localhost/arriendo/Hora.php?centroid=111&cancha=1&date=2015-11-22`

`$cod=$_GET["centroid"];`
`$cancha=$_GET["cancha"];`
`$date=$_GET["date"];`

`$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Hora FROM reserva3 WHERE Cod_centro='$cod'`
 `AND Cancha='$cancha' AND Fecha='$date'");`

Comment: Can you dump your MYSQL Schema for the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what is wrong with your query try debugging it
Here's how I debug query's

1. echo the query to the screen

   ```
   $query= "SELECT Hora FROM reserva3 WHERE Cod_centro='$cod'  AND Cancha='$cancha' AND Fecha='$date'";
   echo $query;
   ```
2. copy the printed query from the screen
3. execute the query in you db manager (phpmyadmin)
4. Read the sql error and
5. change your query accordingly

Assumming you have a timestamp (not only date) I think you can change your query from

```
SELECT Hora FROM reserva3 WHERE Cod_centro='$cod'  AND Cancha='$cancha' AND Fecha='$date'
```

to

```
SELECT Hora FROM reserva3 WHERE Cod_centro='$cod'  AND date(Cancha)='$cancha' AND Fecha='$date'
```

If this works it's because of formatting why the first query didn't work. otherwise you have to add your sql error here, so we can fix.

Comment: thanks bro date(Fecha)='$date' was the solution, really I appreciate